# Node.js concat array after async.concat()

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I have an array, I need to recompile with the use of some edits. I do it with the help of [`async.concat()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#concat), but something is not working.
Tell me, where is the mistake?

```
async.concat(dialogs, function(dialog, callback) {
    if (dialog['viewer']['user_profile_image'] != null) {
        fs.exists(IM.pathToUserImage + dialog['viewer']['user_profile_image'].replace('%s', ''), function(exits) {
            if (exits) {
                dialog['viewer']['user_profile_image'] = dialog['viewer']['user_profile_image'].replace('%s', '');
            }
            callback(dialog);
        });
    }
}, function() {
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

In my opinion, everything is logical. callback is invoked immediately after the first iteration. But how can I send the data after the completion of processing the entire array?

**Thank you!**

Comment: What does the `console.log` call log? What's unexpected with the result?

Comment: @Bergi In the callback comes only one element of the array.

Comment: Ah, that's because you're "throwing" an error. Use the second argument to `callback` instead.

Comment: @Bergi look comments for the first answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem but did not understand its meaning. The problem was due to the element which was null instead of the processed value. The program broke off at this point, but do not throw away any errors / warnings.

```
async.map(dialogs, function(dialog, callback) {
    if (dialog['viewer']['user_profile_image'] == null) {
        dialog['viewer']['user_profile_image'] = IM.pathToUserImage;
    }
    fs.exists(IM.pathToUserImage + dialog['viewer']['user_profile_image'].replace('%s', ''), function(exits) {
        if (exits) {
            dialog['viewer']['user_profile_image'] = dialog['viewer']['user_profile_image'].replace('%s', '');
        }
        callback(null, dialog);
    });
}, function(err, rows) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(rows);
});
```

Comment: You *always* have to call the callback function passed by `async` to your handler function. In your initial example, you didn't call it if `dialog['viewer']['user_profile_image']` happened to be `null`. That will probably have resulted in undefined behavior.

Comment: Why are you using `async.concat()` here and not `async.map()`?

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny Because I need to collect all of the elements of the array into one. But, frankly, I do not quite understand the difference between `.concat` and `.map`.

Comment: @robertklep I was confused what `node.js` did not throw any error.

Comment: @RomanGorbatko I edited your answer and replaced `async.concat` with `async.map`. I hope it'll explain you the difference. See [answer revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17703744/revisions) for more details.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny Can you explain, in practice, what basic difference between these two methods?

Comment: `async.map` maps each element of an array into a new one, resulting in a new array of the same length. `async.concat` maps each element of an array into an array of sub-elements and then concatenates all them into one array. So, with `async.concat` you can produce an array of any length, while `async.map` will always produce an array of the same length as the original one.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `callback(dialog);`, you want

`callback(null,dialog);`

because the first parameter to the callback function is an error object.  The reason that `console.log(arguments)` is getting called after the first iteration is because `async` thinks an error occurred.

Comment: I think it is not fundamentally important. But even with that there is a problem, if I pass the callback in the first argument `null`, nothing inside `callback` it does not work, even `console.log(arguments);`

Comment: @RomanGorbatko: The documentation also says that the second value that is passed to the `callback` should be an array.  It looks like `dialog` is an object?

Comment: No, `dialog` is a object. But, if done well: `callback (null, [dialog])`, we get the same thing - nothing

Comment: If I as the first argument is null then the inside `callback`, nothing happens, but if you pass something like `123` - works.

Answer (score 0):

Though I am a little late to post this answer, I see none of us has used .concat function in the way it supposed to be used.

I have created a snippet that says the proper implementation of this function.

```js
let async = require('async');
async.concat([1, 2, 3], hello, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result); // [1, 3]
});

function hello(time, callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        callback(time, null)
    }, time * 500);
}
```